# Using PHP to syntax highlight all <code>s on a page... ($highlight_string() isn't an option)

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax-highlighting, preg-replace

I'm using CodeIgniter, alongside the `highlight_code("$string");` ([More info](http://www.codeignitor.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html)) function to provide syntax highlighting to a dynamic site. I want the users to be able to submit their own posts written in a BBCode-style format. I'm using [NBBC PHP library](http://nbbc.sourceforge.net) for this.

My problem is that nomatter how I do it I cannot get NBBC to syntax-highlight only `[code][/code]` tags that my users enter. Here's the PHP for [code]:

```
'code' => Array(
'mode' => BBCODE_MODE_ENHANCED,

'template' => "\n<div class=\"bbcode_code\">\n<p>Code:</p>\n<code><?php $highlight_code(\"?>{\$_content/v}<?php \");?></code>\n</div>\n",
'class' => 'code',
'allow_in' => Array('listitem', 'block', 'columns'),
'content' => BBCODE_VERBATIM,
'before_tag' => "sns",
'after_tag' => "sn",
'before_endtag' => "sn",
'after_endtag' => "sns",
'plain_start' => "<div id=\"footer\">",
'plain_end' => "</div>",
'simple_start' => '\n<div class=\"bbcode_code\">\n<p>Code:</p>\n<code>',
'simple_end'   => '</code>\n</div>\n',
),
```

If you see the line which says `<?php $highlight_code(\"?>{\$_content/v}<?php \");?>` that I whacked in there, I thought that would highlight the code contained within the  tags. I can't quite remember what this outputs (I've tried plenty of different combinations) but the closest I got was it being exported as text from PHP - in my page XHTML source it just appeared as text.

What can I do to make all content within  `tags on a page be syntax-highlighted, ideally using highlight_code($string); or similar?`

I was thinking `preg_replace` would be an option but I don't know how to do it to dynamically replace everything between outputted  tags (not [code], remember, but HTML  which NBBC outputs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use preg_match to extract the contents of the [code][/code] tags, and highlight_code() that.

Use the results to preg_replace() the code area in the original string with the highlighted code.  Pseudocode-ish:

```
$code = preg_match(/code pattern/, $string);
$code = highlight_code($code);
$string = preg_replace(/code pattern/, $code, $string);
```

Hope it works.